# Generating a link based on user input that is copied to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm creating a form for staff to use to generate links. Our website handles payments. The idea is that staff can input say $23 as 23.00 and it will take the user to `example.com/pay/23.00`

Currently pressing the "get link" button takes the user to the payment address.

```html
<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://example.com/pay/" + document.getElementById("url").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("url");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the URL: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
<form onSubmit="return process();">
<p>Enter the amount as a decimal:</p><br>
<input type="text" name="url" id="url"> <input type="submit" value="Get Link" id="paylink">
</form>
```

Pressing `get link` should copy the URL rather than redirect.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm almost there.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
function process()
{
   var url="http://example.com/pay/" + document.getElementById("url").value;
   document.getElementById("url").value = url;
   var copyText = document.getElementById("url");
   copyText.select();
   document.execCommand("copy");
   alert("Copied the URL: " + copyText.value);
   return false;
}
</script>
<p>Enter the amount as a decimal:</p><br>
<input type="text" name="url" id="url"> <input type="button" onclick="process()" value="Get Link" id="paylink">
```

Moreover, you should put some verification.